# How do I avoid memory leak when concat string pointers in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory-leaks, concatenation

I am working on a parser for a programming languages class and am having a memory leak issue while turning my expression tree to a string in the preorder arrangement. Before i had it that when allocating memory to string in exprToString it was 100 * sizeof(char), however the mem leakage results were far greater. So, i got rid of the 100 * but i still get non ascii printouts and the odd recurring "retu"...

```
char* concat(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    char *result = malloc(strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1);//+1 for the null-
    terminator
    //free(result);
    //in real code you would check for errors in malloc here
    strcpy(result, s1);
    strcat(result, s2);
    return result;
}

char* exprToString(Expr* ex){
    char *string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    //free(string);
    if(strcmp(ex->value,"18killstreak") == 0){
        return " ";
    }
    string = concat(string,ex->value);
    string = concat(string,exprToString(ex->a));
    string = concat(string,exprToString(ex->b));
    return string;
}
```

here is a sample expression: z / ( x + 2 * x )
here is the printout : 0etur/z   +x   *2   x

Whats happening?

Comment: `char *string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));` allocates only 1 byte... and non nul terminated so further `strlen` calls return undefined values and you're adding one garbage string with the other.

Comment: So i just need to append \0 to all my strings before concat?

Comment: no that was just the first mistake. Memory leak is explained in my answer.

Comment: take a look at realloc, it should solve your problem with returning a new buffer every time and creating memory leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `concat` function is okay but the start of `exprToString` is wrong:

```
    char *string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));    
    string = concat(string,ex->value);
```

you're allocating only a 1 byte string, and it's not even nul-terminated, so further call to `concat` concatenates some string with undefined length with `ex->value`.

If what you want is initialize `string` with a copy of `ex-value`, just replace the above with:

```
char *string = strdup(ex->value);
```

The next problem is a memory leak when doing this:

```
string = concat(string,exprToString(ex->a));
```

you're overwriting the previous value of `string`, so it works but you get a memory leak because you don't have a chance to free the input.

You could change `concat` so it frees the first argument by calling:

```
free(s1);
```

just before returning the result. Or use `realloc` on `s1` so it frees then resizes.

But both are not very handy. What if some caller doesn't read the docs, needs the string for something else, of if you're passing a literal as first argument ? That would make your `concat` function not so useful and error prone (unless it's called with a very special name for this very special purpose)

The simplest way is to decompose your `concat` call:

```
char *temp = concat(string,ex->value);
free(string);
string = temp;
```

C language doesn't have a lot of magic behind the scenes, like operator overloading or garbage collection, so everything must be written explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

There are (at least) two serious bugs in the current code in the question:

> ```
> char* exprToString(Expr* ex){
>     char *string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
>     //free(string);
>     if(strcmp(ex->value,"18killstreak") == 0){
>         return " ";
>     }
>     string = concat(string,ex->value);
>     string = concat(string,exprToString(ex->a));
>     string = concat(string,exprToString(ex->b));
>     return string;
> }
> ```

First, and most subtle, is that you sometimes (mostly) return pointer to allocated memory, but sometimes return a pointer to a constant string.  That means the calling code cannot reliably call `free()` on the returned value, which either leads to subtle (or maybe not so subtle) memory corruption when the returned pointer is freed or it leads to leaks because the returned pointer is never freed.  Neither is satisfactory.  Make sure that if you return a pointer, it can uniformly be released.  Consider returning a NULL pointer instead of the single-blank string, but if you must return the single-blank string, make sure you allocate it.  Note that the early return leaks memory too, completely unnecessarily.

Second, and more serious, you have to preserve pointers to the memory returned by `concat` so you can free all except the value returned to the caller.

The first problem is at:

```
char *string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

You don't check the memory allocation succeeded.  You don't ensure that you have a string.  You need `*string = '\0';` to be safe.

Then you have:

```
string = concat(string, ex->value);
```

After this, you've lost the only pointer to the memory allocated by the first `malloc()` — which is the very definition of a memory leak.  The next two lines make the same mistake; you've leaked 3 blocks of memory before you return.

One solution to this is:

```
char* exprToString(Expr* ex){
    if (strcmp(ex->value, "18killstreak") == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    char *string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    if (string == 0)
        return 0;
    *string = '\0';
    char *t1 = concat(string, ex->value);
    free(string);
    string = t1;
    t1 = concat(string, exprToString(ex->a));
    free(string);
    string = t1;
    string = concat(string, exprToString(ex->b));
    free(string);
    string = t1;
    return string;
}
```

That begins to look unpleasantly repetitive.  An alternative solution changes `concat()` — both the code and the semantics.  If you demand that the first pointer be a pointer to freeable (reallocatable) memory, you can use:

```
char *concat(char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    if (s1 == 0)
        return 0;
    size_t len_1 = strlen(s1);
    size_t len_2 = strlen(s2);
    char *result = realloc(s1, len_1 + len_2 + 1);
    if (result == 0)
    {
        free(s1);
        return 0;
    }
    strcat(result, s2);
    return result;
}
```

Now you can use a slightly modified version of your original code:

```
  char* exprToString(Expr* ex){
    if (strcmp(ex->value, "18killstreak") == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    char *string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    if (string == 0)
        return 0;
    *string = '\0';
    string = concat(string, ex->value);
    string = concat(string, exprToString(ex->a));
    string = concat(string, exprToString(ex->b));
    return string;
}
```

Now there are only options on more leaks because `exprToString()` returns a pointer to allocated memory that you never free.  There are multiple ways to deal with that, too.  One such is for `concat()` to be redefined to take *two* pointers to freeable (reallocatable) memory and free the second pointer before returning.  You then have to worry about the call `string = concat(string, ex->value);` — one safe alternative would be `string = concat(string, strdup(ex->value));`, for example.  (At least, it's safe if the `concat()` function checks for null pointers.)

There may be other problems I've not spotted yet.  The suggested code has not been past a compiler — there could be bugs in it.  In particular, I've not fully tracked what happens after every possible explicit allocation failure; there could be issues in the error recovery code.

There are those who are adamantly opposed to [casting the result of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/).  I'm not adamant about it if you guarantee that you compile with options that ensure that `malloc()` is declared before it is used.  I followed the original code in leaving the casts in place.

Answer (score 2):

Here's where the memory leak is coming from:

```
char *string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
...
string = concat(string,ex->value);
string = concat(string,exprToString(ex->a));
string = concat(string,exprToString(ex->b));
```

Every time you call `concat`, you overwrite the current value of `string`, which contains a pointer to malloc'ed memory, with a new pointer value, discarding the old value.

You should change `concat` to use `realloc` on the first parameter if it is not NULL.  That way you can grow the buffer as needed.  On the initial call to `concat`, you would set the first parameter to NULL.

So modify `concat` to use `realloc`:

```
char* concat(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    char *result;
    if (s1) {
        result = realloc(s1, strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1);
        if (!result) {
            perror("realloc failed");
            free(s1);
            return NULL;
        }
        strcpy(result, s2);
    } else {
        result = malloc(strlen(s2)+1);
        if (!result) {
            perror("malloc failed");
            return NULL;
        }
        strcat(result, s2);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then you change `exprToString` to :

```
char* exprToString(Expr* ex){
    if(strcmp(ex->value,"18killstreak") == 0){
        return strdup(" ");
    }
    char *string = concat(NULL,ex->value);
    char *a_str = exprToString(ex->a);
    char *b_str = exprToString(ex->b);
    string = concat(string,a_str);
    string = concat(string,b_str);
    free(a_str);
    free(b_str);
    return string;
}
```

Note that because this function is expected to return dynamically allocated memory that the base case cannot return a string literal directly.  Whoever calls this function is responsible for freeing the buffer that was returned.

Comment: Note that if `concat()` is going to free its second argument (or `realloc()` its first) then it is essential that its arguments, when non-NULL, be pointers to dynamically-allocated memory.  With the OP's current implementation of `exprToString()`, that is certain sometimes to *not* be the case.  Which should be fixed in `exprToString()`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The second argument can be any string.  It's only the first one that has to point to dynamically alllocated memory.

Comment: Ah.  I see I read your code too fast.  Am I mistaken, then, in thinking that your answer does not address the memory leakage arising from `exprToString()`'s recursion?

Comment: @JohnBollinger You are correct, I missed that `exprToString` is recursive.  That complicates things a bit.  I'll update to address that.